# Confirmation that Platform Event objects can be created dynamically (starting from an API name string)

Tags: platform-event, dynamic-apex

I'm looking for confirmation that a [Platform Event](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform_events_basics) SObject can be created starting from the API name of the type using e.g. `Type.formName('...').newInstance()` just as a normal custom SObject can be.

(We want to have several managed packages generating the same Platform Event type defined in a logging managed package. See https://github.com/afawcett/eventlogging for one logging example.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a legal operation. This works in one of my orgs:

```
sObject d = (sObject)Type.forName('Demo__e').newInstance();
EventBus.publish(d);
```

Comment: Thanks! In a discussion tomorrow where this is being assumed so I wanted to check.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence here. I believe that type.forName() doesn't work with a Platform Event object if you're inside a Platform Event Trigger. Was looking to do just that a while back (Summer '19) and had to re-architect my solution because PEs didn't allow me to get into my trigger framework (which relies on Type.forName() to dispatch to an appropriate class).

Comment: Hi @DerekF, Thanks for the heads up... Inside a PE trigger or inside any trigger? For our logging, inside a "normal" trigger is an important case.

Comment: @KeithC I only recall trying in a PE trigger (which didn't work) and in anonymous apex (which _did_ work). I think being in the same transaction as a PE Trigger is where the issue arises.

Comment: Thanks again @DerekF; I'll test myself in "normal" triggers.

Comment: @KeithC, have you tried in Normal Trigger whether it is Working or Not

Comment: @GauravJain It seems to have worked when I tested it.